# equivalency of some facts in $O$ notation

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, data-structures, asymptotics, discrete-mathematics

I misunderstanding about some logarithm property in algorithm course:

is it correct that we say following three term is equivalent?

$O(\log a + \log b)$

$O(\log (ab))$

$O(\log (a+b))$

Comment: $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$ is an elementary property of the logarithms.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a>b>0$. From $\log(a+b)=\log(a)+\log\left(1+\dfrac ba\right)$, we draw

$$\log(a)\le\log(a+b)\le \log(a)+\log(2)$$ and similarly for $b>a$.

Comment: You may want to add the case when a = b.

Comment: @MaryamPanahi: what do you mean ?

Comment: @MaryamPanahi: did you read the first sentence ?